# Let Ax=0 be an homogeneous system with n variables. Then the dimension of the nullspace of A is n-r(A).

Tags: linear-algebra

Comments on the proof as well as any simpler or alternative approaches using matrices would be appreciated, thanks. The theorem is similar to the Rank-Nullity theorem which I am able to prove and don't need assistance on.

Theorem:
Let Ax=0 be an homogeneous system with n variables. Then the dimension of the nullspace of A is n-r(A) (where r(A) is the rank of A, the number of non-zero rows in A in row echelon form).

Proof outline: 
In step 1 we take k free variables (FVs) as the number of FVs is equal to n-r(A). In step 2 we create a general solution vector from FVs; if we can show that a basis of the nullspace (general solution set to Ax=0) has k elements the proof is complete. In steps 3-4 we determine a basis from the general solution set that has k elements. As there is a basis with k elements the dimension of the nullspace is k and we conclude in step 5. These steps are in more detail below:

1. The theorem states that n-r(A) is the dimension of the nullspace of A (nullity of A). The number of FVs in the system is also n-r(A). Let k equal the number of FVs, k=n-r(A).
2. With k FVs a general solution vector to the system (column vector x in Ax=0) is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ ...\\ x_k\\ x_{k+1}\\...\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$$ =$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ ...\\ x_k\\ a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_kx_k\\...\\b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+b_kx_k\end{pmatrix}$$ Where $x_1,...,x_n$ are the variables in the general solution vector, $x_1,...,x_k$ are the FVs, and $x_{k+1},...,x_n$ are the pivot variables (PVs). The PVs are linear combinations of the FVs (the FVs may not be in the first k rows of the solution vector, however elementary row operations can be performed to place the FVs in the first k rows).

3.$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ ...\\ x_k\\ a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_kx_k\\...\\b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+b_kx_k\end{pmatrix}$$ = $$x_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\...\\0\\a_1\\...\\b_1\end{pmatrix}+...+x_k\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\...\\1\\a_k\\...\\b_k\end{pmatrix}$$=$$x_1w_1+...+x_kw_k$$

4. {$w_1,...,w_k$} is a linearly independent (LI) set in the nullspace of A. If $w_1,...,w_k$ were placed as row vectors in a matrix it would be in row reduced echelon form (RREF) and, by a theorem that states the non-zero rows of a matrix in echelon form are LI, {$w_1,...,w_k$} is a LI set.
5. {$w_1,...,w_k$} also spans the solution set as every solution to Ax=0 can be written as a linear combination of these vectors. Therefore by definition {$w_1,...,w_k$} is a basis of the nullspace of A with k elements. Also by definition the dimension of the nullspace (nullity of A) is k and, as k=n-r(A), the dimension of the nullspace is n-r(A). Q.E.D.

Comment: If you have already proven the rank-nullity theorem, why not simply apply this theorem to the linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ given by $T(x) = Ax$?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My rank-nullity proof has more steps than this proof.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about point 4, the vectors $w_1,w_2,\cdots, w_k$ aren't exactly the rows of the matrix echelon form.